# Solving linear equations using matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm doing little program, where I need to solve multiple linear equations like:
$$\begin{align*}
B_1 &= A_{11}C_1 + A_{12}C_2 + A_{13}C_3 + A_{14}C_4\\
B_2 &= A_{21}C_1 + A_{22}C_2 + A_{23}C_3 + A_{24}C_4\\
B_3 &= A_{31}C_1 + A_{32}C_2 + A_{33}C_3 + A_{34}C_4\\
B_4 &= A_{41}C_1 + A_{42}C_2 + A_{43}C_3 + A_{44}C_4
\end{align*}
$$

All $A_{ij}$ and $B_j$ values are known. I heard it can be done by matrix solving, but I haven't learned it in the school yet. I can't find any article about it by google, because I have no idea  what it's called.

Now the question: **How is the procedure to solve these linear equations using matrix?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The system of linear equations that you wrote down can be succinctly expressed by arranging the numbers $A_{11}, \dotsc, A_{44}$ in a matrix $A$ and the numbers $B_1, \dotsc,B_4$ and $C_1, \dotsc,C_4$ in vectors $b$ and $c$, respectively. Then the system can be written $b=Ac$, or, more conventionally, $Ac=b$. If you don't understand this notation, you might want to take a look at [matrix multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication).

But this is just a convenient way of collecting all the values that belong together in approriately structured objects -- you don't necessarily have to understand any of that in order to solve the system. The standard algorithm to solve systems of linear equations is [Gaussian elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination). That's what you should use if you want to solve a system only once. If you need to solve several systems with the same matrix $A$ (i.e. the same values $A_{11},\dotsc,A_{44}$) but different vectors $b$ (i.e. different values $B_1,\dotsc,B_4$), there are more efficient ways of doing that. Responding to your comment: It's not that other ways of solving systems of linear equations are "better" in general; it depends on what you want to do. If you want to solve several systems with the same matrix $A$, then it makes sense to do as much preprocessing as possible on $A$ before bringing the individual $b$s into play; whereas if you have only one $b$ to solve for, it's easier and faster to just plug it in right from the start.

If you want to learn more about other methods, there are some pointers in [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Other_methods).

Comment: if there are any better ways to solve it, can u please show them, i've edited the question

Comment: @Miro: From your edit, it seems that some further explanations are required -- I'll be adding them shortly.

Comment: My problem is to get blur coefficients from A source image and B blured image. Theres total 9 C unknowns.

Comment: But you have answered the question. I'll create another question for my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You might take a look at [Gaussian Elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination).  Any numerical analysis book will have a chapter on this, such as chapter 2 of [Numerical Recipes](http://nr.com/) (the obsolete versions are free)